# Kyestone client commands fails when called inside bash script

Tags: bash, ubuntu, openstack, keystone

I am making a small bash script that tries to install keystone and create the initial admin user, tenant, etc..
I tried it with various keystone subcommands and they all fail saying:

> Unable to establish connection to httx://10.0.2.100:35357/v2.0/tenants

I tried sourcing the env variables via a file, using export and in last resort even running the command with `--os-token` and `--os-endpoint`. Here is the latest version that I used inside the script:

> keystone --debug --os-token secret --os-endpoint httx://10.0.2.100:35357/v2.0 tenant-list

The full message with debug is the following:

> WARNING: Bypassing authentication using a token & endpoint (authentication credentials are being ignored).
>   DEBUG:keystoneclient.session:REQ: curl -i -X GET httx://10.0.2.100:35357/v2.0/tenants -H "User-Agent: python-keystoneclient" -H "X-Auth-Token: secret"
>   INFO:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): 10.0.2.100
>   Unable to establish connection to httx://10.0.2.100:35357/v2.0/tenants

But if I ran the same command directly on the bash shell I have no issues. Here is the debug output for it:

> keystone --debug --os-token secret --os-endpoint httx://10.0.2.100:35357/v2.0 tenant-list
>   WARNING: Bypassing authentication using a token & endpoint (authentication credentials are being ignored).
>   DEBUG:keystoneclient.session:REQ: curl -i -X GET httx://10.0.2.100:35357/v2.0/tenants -H "User-Agent: python-keystoneclient" -H "X-Auth-Token: secret"
>   INFO:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): 10.0.2.100
>   DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Setting read timeout to 600.0
>   DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /v2.0/tenants HTTP/1.1" 200 256
>   DEBUG:keystoneclient.session:RESP: [200] {'date': 'Tue, 17 Mar 2015 14:28:20 GMT', 'vary': 'X-Auth-Token', 'content-length': '256', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'x-distribution': 'Ubuntu'} 
>   RESP BODY: {"tenants_links": [], "tenants": [{"description": "Admin Tenant", "enabled": true, "id": "17008f66b9b54ca39654846e0b5e7af2", "name": "admin"}, {"description": "Service Tenant", "enabled": true, "id": "3a6823c10e454f4294aebdfec8b0c5dd", "name": "service"}]}
>   
>   `+----------------------------------+---------+---------+
>   |                id                |   name  | enabled |
>   +----------------------------------+---------+---------+
>   | 17008f66b9b54ca39654846e0b5e7af2 |  admin  |   True  |
>   | 3a6823c10e454f4294aebdfec8b0c5dd | service |   True  |
>   +----------------------------------+---------+---------+`

So it seems that only when the script tries to run the command it fails...
I cannot figure out why...Any help is appreciated.

PS. I had to replace http with httx in order to be able to post as I do not have enough reputation points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few hours later... I have finally figured out what is wrong. In my script I first restart the keystone service so that the changes to the "/etc/keystone/keystone.conf" file would be taken into account and I run the keystone commands right after. It seems that it does take some time for keystone to be up before answering my commands. I added "sleep 1" in between the two commands and now it works. Maybe it will be useful to somebody :-)